# WPF: How to dynamically Add Controls in dynamically created WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to add a WPF Input Box in my Project in C#. I got a WinForm one from [InputBox in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/edit/InputBox.aspx) but it has Winform look and feel. So i was recreating it in WPF. I have created all the controls (Label, Button, Textbox) but i am unable to add them to my window.

```
static Window winInputDialog
```

The Window is showing through ShowDialog but without controls.

Comment: How are you calling this window to show itself? `Window.ShowDialog()`?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

There are two ways to get controls in your window:

1. Do the whole designing stuff in the Designer of VisualStudio
2. Add the controls by code. Here is a short, simple sample of creating a window and putting controls in it:

   ```
   var window = new Window();
   var stackPanel = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
   stackPanel.Children.Add(new Label { Content = "Label" });
   stackPanel.Children.Add(new Button { Content = "Button" });
   window.Content = stackPanel;
   ```

Comment: How to change position of created label in code?