# Add Rect from another class in c#

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to draw a rect from another class in c#
into my mainWindow

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Name="mainWindow" Height="768" Width="1366" >
</Window>
```

Here is my Class code snippet which I tried to draw a rect to mainWindow

```
private UIElement container;

private Rect rect1 = new Rect();

public TestPage(UIElement cont) 
{        
    this.container = cont;
}

private void init()
{
    this.container.Children.Add(rect1);
}
```

How to handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Window can have only one content so you have to set `Content` property of Window.

Comment: I googled but I dont know which value the Content property of my mainWindow should be set. Any hint?

Comment: @bbklol: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884185/wpf-how-to-dynamically-add-controls-in-dynamically-created-wpf-window