# Event loaded in code-behind

Tags: c#, xaml, code-behind

I have an expander with a loaded event in xaml, and it works well :

```
<Expander Name="exp" Loaded="expander_Loaded">
```

But I try in code-behind :

```
   Expander ex = new Expander();
   ex.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(expander_Loaded);

   void expander_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
        //code
   }
```

And it doesn't work.

How can i call `expander_Loaded` when my expander isLoaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use

```
<Expander Name="exp" Loaded="expander_Loaded">
```

you insert a new Expander into your XAML, i.e. the display knows about it and works with it.

When you do:

```
Expander ex = new Expander();
ex.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(expander_Loaded);

void expander_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //code
}
```

you create a new `Expander` object, assign it an event, and then, if it is not used after that line, promptly discard it. Try

```
<Expander Name="exp">
```

with

```
//refers to the declared object
exp.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(expander_Loaded);

void expander_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //code
}
```

to see that it will work. Additionally, if you want to create and add controls at runtime, take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884185/wpf-how-to-dynamically-add-controls-in-dynamically-created-wpf-window), that explains working with the [`Children`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.children.aspx) collection

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to hook up the event in code *and* in markup. Either remove `Loaded="expander_Loaded"` or remove `ex.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(expander_Loaded);`. It's possible doing it twice is having this unexpected effect.

Comment: The event in markup it's just to have an example of what I want to do in code.