# Dynamic Search Criteria in C# .net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, dynamic-controls

I have to create a form in which the user can select fields from a listbox on which he wants the search criteria and then the controls are created according to the selection of the user from the listbox,for example if the listbox consist of fields like

```
 1. Name
 2. Age
 3. Department
 4. Designation
```

and if the user wants to have a search based on the `Name` and `Designation` then he will select `Name` and `Designation` from list box and the two text boxes will be created in the search panel with their respective lables,

And if the user wants to put the search criteria on `Age` then he can replace the previously selected `Name` and `Designation` field with `Age` and then only 1 TextBox will be created with label age in the search panel,

So what is the best possible way to achieve this requirement,please suggest me,any sort of help will be highly appreciable

Thanks in Advance

Comment: i want to write the code in C# with oracle as back-end

Comment: what you have commented is correct,but for the later part but initially i want to generate the search criteria panel according to the field selected by the user,like i have mentioned in my question

Comment: i want to know how to create dynamic controls based on the fields selected fro eg. if user selects Name and age the two text boxes should be created in the search criteria panel

Comment: i think the best approach would be to write some jscript which will add/remove or enable/disable textboxes when selected item is changed

Comment: thanks for your suggestion i am implementing the code with your helps thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding controls dynamically is not a hard concept, Just do searches for adding controls dynamically to whatever UI technology you are using.

Here is a basic tutorial that adds a Textbox to a webform http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/adding-web-forms-controls-dynamically-in-Asp-Net-C-Sharp-web-appl/

Using JQuery http://totaldotnet.com/article/showarticle130_dynamiccontroljquery.aspx

A question about adding to WPF [WPF: How to dynamically Add Controls in dynamically created WPF Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884185/wpf-how-to-dynamically-add-controls-in-dynamically-created-wpf-window)

Or Windows Form, http://anthonystechblog.wordpress.com/2009/11/12/net-c-how-to-dynamicall-add-controls-to-a-form-and-hook-up-their-events/

Comment: thank u very much i got the correct path for starting with the implementation of my code your suggetions helped me to start thans again