# TextBox cannot be edit

Tags: c#, wpf

I find a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884185/wpf-how-to-dynamically-add-controls-in-dynamically-created-wpf-window) to generate form only in code.

But when i try to add a `TextBox` to the panel, it cannot be edit.

```
var window = new Window();
var stackPanel = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
stackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBox { Text = "Text" } );
window.Content = stackPanel;
```

Comment: It work perfectly. Does `TextBox` works okay in XAML ?

Comment: @Nitesh Please check my comments below the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this, and it works fine.

```
private void Test_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var window = new Window();
    var stackPanel = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Vertical };
    stackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBox { Text = "Text" });
    window.Content = stackPanel;
    window.Show();
}

<Window x:Class="WPF_Test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="Test" Content="Click Me" Click="Test_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When you click on the button in the Main Window, it opens up a new window with a text box which can be edited.

Comment: I am not use a xmal file here, I just write the `.cs` file.

Comment: Please check my code here: https://gist.github.com/prehistoricpenguin/6227834

Comment: @prehistoricpenguin The word "TextBox" does not appear in your gist apart from in comments. You're adding a TextBlock (ie static text like a label) to your panel.