# How to Dynamically Generate WPF Elements in Ironpython

Tags: wpf, xaml, ironpython

I'm using Ironpython 2.7. Is it possible to dynamically generate elements of a wpf window based on data found at runtime? The program will call a database and load parameters, and I'd like to generate a TextBox (and ComboBox) for each parameter loaded (e.g. if 4 parameters are loaded, the window will show 4 TextBoxes with corresponding ComboBoxes).

Is this something I can do with a property decorator? Will I have to generate the xaml dynamically to do this? For example:

```
    import wpf
    from System import Windows.Window

    parameters = loadfromdatabase(args)....
    xaml_filename = "program.xaml"
    textBox_list = ""
    cnt = 0
    for param in parameters:
        textBox_list += '<TextBox x:Name={} HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="21" Width = "52" Margin="60,{},0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>\n'.format(param,60+26*cnt)
        cnt += 1
    xaml_string = "<Window \n<Grid>\n" + textBox_list + "</Grid>\n</Window>"

    with open(xaml_filename, "w") as f:
        f.write(xaml_string)

    class MyWindow(Window):
        def __init__(self):
            wpf.LoadComponent(self, xaml_filename)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        Application().Run(MyWindow())
```

Answer (score 0):

You would dynamically generate WPF element in IronPython the same way you would do so in C#. See [WPF: How to dynamically Add Controls in dynamically created WPF Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884185/wpf-how-to-dynamically-add-controls-in-dynamically-created-wpf-window) for how to do it in C#.

Comment: The method I suggested worked as well. Do all of the references in the C# example you mentioned translate directly to IronPython?

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Just write as you normally would in C#, except using Python syntax.

Comment: Writing in XAML has its advantages, but if you must write Python code, then spare yourself the trouble of having to write XAML.