# Get Json elements and generate UI Controls Dynamic in WPF C#

Tags: c#, json, wpf, xaml

I was trying create some UI elements in my WPF application. I took this example: [WPF: How to dynamically Add Controls in dynamically created WPF Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884185/wpf-how-to-dynamically-add-controls-in-dynamically-created-wpf-window) as reference. But, my interface was a mess. You can see by image below:

[Actual FORM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycR5D.jpg)

This is the code that got the `JSON`:

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        db = new DbItens("DBItens");

        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var get = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootJson>(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(webClient.DownloadData(url)));
            foreach (var item in get.Itens)
            {

                buildForm(item, prox);
                prox++;
            }
        }
    }
```

And this is my `buildForm` method:

```
 private void buildForm(Item item, int prox)
    {
        stkSPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;

        stkSPanel.Children.Add(new Label
        {
            Content = item.Nome,
        });
        stkSPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock
        {
            Text = item.Descricao,
        });

        Image img = new Image
        {
            Height = 100,
            Width = 100

        };
        img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(item.Foto));
        StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
        panel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
        panel.Margin = new Thickness(10);
        panel.Children.Add(img);


        stkSPanel.Children.Add(new Button {Content = panel });
    }
```

How i can format this elements?

Note: My code need to be that way (not directly implemented  in XAML), because i will get new items from database too (I only have the `stackPanel` in XAML), and i need show then by `heapsort algorithm`.

XAML Code:

```
<Window x:Class="BlueGearAPP.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BlueGearAPP"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">

    <StackPanel x:Name="stkSPanel"></StackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

I want something like this:

[Expected Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2vsq.jpg)

**ANSWER**

Talking with [sumodh-s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4349259/sumodh-s) i've been changed my panels orientation to vertival, and my UI controls to horizontal with alignment in center. And now it's worked fine.

Comment: I would like to know why you have set the orientation of stack panel to horizontal when you want the elements to stack vertically?

Comment: I was trying something and forgot to go back to the previous code. Thanks, I'll edit it.

Comment: Now also you are getting the same problem?

Comment: Well, I do not understand why my previous work even putting as vertical was getting confused. It seems that now it's worked. My changes are have put the two panels as vertically and my UI elements horizontally aligned to the center.