# C# Wpf Create Image and labels with for loop

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to create an image and label with a loop on C#. I created objects using the drag and drop method and I gave names of all objects and create events manuely. But I need to do this on code behind. I need to use the MouseLeftButtonDown event on image objects. How can I create form objects and events on code behind in a loop?

Form Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="EnerjiKontrolTakipSistemi.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EnerjiKontrolTakipSistemi"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="1080" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Loaded="Window_Loaded"  >
    <Grid>
        <Image x:Name="ImageSigorta1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="155" Margin="38,53,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72" Stretch="Fill" MouseLeftButtonDown="ImageSigorta1_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblSigorta1Voltaj" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="55,69,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.708,0.278" Foreground="#FFF74B4B" FontWeight="Bold" Background="{x:Null}"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblSigorta1Amper" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="55,165,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.708,0.278" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFF74B4B" Background="{x:Null}"/>
        <Image x:Name="ImageSigorta2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="155" Margin="150,53,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="72" Stretch="Fill" MouseLeftButtonDown="ImageSigorta2_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblSigorta2Voltaj" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="167,69,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.708,0.278" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFF74B4B" Background="{x:Null}"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblSigorta2Amper" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="167,165,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.708,0.278" Foreground="#FFF74B4B" FontWeight="Bold" Background="{x:Null}"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblSigorta1Watt" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="51,210,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.708,0.278" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFF74B4B" Background="{x:Null}"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblSigorta2Watt" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="163,210,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.708,0.278" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFF74B4B" Background="{x:Null}"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblSigortaAdi1" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="42,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.708,0.278" Foreground="#FFF74B4B" FontWeight="Bold" Background="{x:Null}"/>
        <Label x:Name="lblSigortaAdi2" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="154,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-0.708,0.278" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFF74B4B" Background="{x:Null}"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code Behind

```
List<Tuple<string, string>> SigortaDurumlari = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SigortaDurumlariniCek();
        ResimleriGetir();
    }

    private void SigortaDurumlariniCek()
    {
        SigortaDurumlari.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Sigorta1", "false"));
        SigortaDurumlari.Add(new Tuple<string, string>("Sigorta2", "true"));
    }

    private void ResimleriGetir()
    {

        ImageSigorta1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images\salter_acik.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
        lblSigortaAdi1.Content = "Sigorta 1";
        lblSigorta1Voltaj.Content = "220 V";
        lblSigorta1Amper.Content = "500 A";
        lblSigorta1Watt.Content = "3800W";



        ImageSigorta2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images\salter_kapali.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
        lblSigortaAdi2.Content = "Sigorta 2";
        lblSigorta2Voltaj.Content = "220 V";
        lblSigorta2Amper.Content = "500 A";
        lblSigorta2Watt.Content = "5400W";
    }

    bool sigorta_durumu1 = false;
    private void ImageSigorta1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
     
        if (sigorta_durumu1 == false)
        {
            ImageSigorta1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images\salter_kapali.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
            sigorta_durumu1 = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ImageSigorta1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images\salter_acik.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
            sigorta_durumu1 = false;
        }
    }
    bool sigorta_durumu2 = false;
    private void ImageSigorta2_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        
        if (sigorta_durumu2 == false)
        {
            ImageSigorta2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images\salter_kapali.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
            sigorta_durumu2 = true;
        }
        else
        {
            ImageSigorta2.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images\salter_acik.jpg", UriKind.Relative));
            sigorta_durumu2 = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Form Runtime Image

[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKLvF.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884185/wpf-how-to-dynamically-add-controls-in-dynamically-created-wpf-window Check this one

Comment: You may want to use an ItemsControl. See [Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).

Comment: Topics are irrelevant @ÖzgürGüzeldereli